# How to get an Indian visa from outside the US?

Tags: visas, india, us-citizens

I booked a tour to India and Nepal from the US, but the Indian Embassy only granted me a single-entry visa.

Is it possible to get a visa to re-enter India from Nepal?

Is there any other way to do it without having to cancel my Nepal trip?

---

Edit by Gayot, the information below was provided as an 'answer', but actually forms a necessary part of this question:

US citizen, 15 days tour included 6 days in Nepal, back to Delhi for 3 days before flying back to California.

Comment: Fly home from Nepal.

Comment: Normally US citizens get a multiple entry visa valid for either 6 months, 5 years or 10 years.  One has to ask why you got only a single entry.  If the embassy shut you down, you may also encounter difficulty applying elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be qualified to apply for an e-Tourist Visa ([eTV](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/tvoa.html)) which if granted should allow you to enter India after having visited Nepal and catch your return flight from Delhi. This takes a minimum of four days but is all online so where you are does not matter. An eTV is valid for a single entry (except to certain areas which you should not need to visit) over a 30 day period so you could apply before reaching Nepal.

> This facility is in addition to the existing Visa services.

So, I think, should not interfere with your existing visa.